Code is executing but in mobile white screen appears in android studio in log cat it showing some errors please check it and please give solutions
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 149
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Otp}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:902)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:865)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:748)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
at com.example.myapplication.Otp.onCreate(Otp.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3704)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049) 

I am trying but I did not find what the error is.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21814825/150978


You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
activity

check if the theme is set correctly in the manifest for the application and activity

ok danila thank you for your response
